# How to upload an image on one server and save it on another using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, server, asp.net-3.5

Recently i came across a requirement in which i need to host my website on my server, and the databases for different client will be in there respective servers. Now for data in database i can handle the connection string dynamically. But what about media files which we save on the server machine??

How can we handle this scenario?

Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You can upload files to a folder in Server 1 and create virtual directory in Server 2 and path for this directory would be of Server1 folder.

Comment: Thanks Mairaj, but i need the images also on the respective servers, i.e. server2.

Comment: Yes it will be accessible on both servers.

Comment: Look on the server where you will upload files you can access without any trouble and on second server you will make virtual directory which will point to first server's folder where actually files are placed so you can access it just like accessing file from a folder.

Comment: Are these both servers on same network or they connected by someway ?

Comment: No the servers are not connected or on same network. The data is required to be saved only on server 2 and not on server 1. Sorry for my previous comment. It caused confusion. I understand that the possible ways might be either to have a FTP location or a web service on server 2. Is there any other way possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options;

now, as if the website server called Server 1,
the database server called Server 2.

Option1, you can upload the image to folder on Server 1,the database just store the image name, image path.

```
//get the file name of the posted image
string imgName = image.FileName.ToString();

String path = Server.MapPath("~/ImageStorage");//Path

//Check if directory exist
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
}

//sets the image path
string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, imgName);

//get the size in bytes that
int imgSize = image.PostedFile.ContentLength;


if (image.PostedFile != null)
{

    if (image.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)//Check if image is greater than 5MB
    {
        //Save image to the Folder
        image.SaveAs(imgPath);
       //also save image path to database
       //......
    }

}
```

Second, you can directly save the image to database on Server2, the column type can use image, byte,binary or blob

```
   public static void PerisitImage(string path, IDbConnection connection)
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand ())
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile (path);
        MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save (tmpStream, ImageFormat.Png); // change to other format
        tmpStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] imgBytes = new byte[MAX_IMG_SIZE];
        tmpStream.Read (imgBytes, 0, MAX_IMG_SIZE);

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO images(payload) VALUES (:payload)";
        IDataParameter par = command.CreateParameter();
        par.ParameterName = "payload";
        par.DbType = DbType.Binary;
        par.Value = imgBytes;
        command.Parameters.Add(par);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack.li. But i need the images also on the respective servers, i.e. server2.

Comment: please see my update, if the images save to database server,then means save to server 2 already, what's your concern?

Comment: Thanks Jack.li. Sorry for the previous comment, it caused some confusion. I mean I need images only on server 2 and in a folder structure and not in database. I understand that the possible ways might be either to have a FTP location or a web service on server 2. Is there any other way possible?